# Angular - How to resolve object is possibly null for a FormGroup

Tags: angular

In Angular-15 project I have this code in the component.ts:

**component.ts:**

```
export class CountryCreateComponent {

  countriesDatas: any[] = [];
  selectedCountryCode: string = '';
  selectedCountryName: string = '';
  createCountryForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {
  }

  createCountry() {
    this.createCountryForm = this.fb.group({
      CountryCode: ['', [Validators.required]],
      CountryName: [''],
    });
  }

createValidate() {
  if (!this.createCountryForm.valid) {
    this.createCountryForm.markAllAsTouched();
    return;
  }
}
get fc() {
  return this.createMerchantForm.controls;
}

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {;

  }

  onCountryChange() {
    const selectedCountry = this.countriesDatas.find(selectedCountryCode => {
      return selectedCountryCode.country_code === this.form.get('countryCode').value;
    });

    if (selectedCountry) {
      this.createCountryForm.get('countryCode').setValue(selectedCountryCode.country_code);
      this.createCountryForm.get('countryName').setValue(selectedCountryName.country_name); 
   }
  }
 }
}
```

However, I got this error:  **object is possibly null**

Then createCountryForm is highlighted in  this.createCountryForm.get

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "nullish coalescing operator" (??) or optional chaining (?.) to handle the possibility of the variable being null.

```
 this.createCountryForm.get('countryCode') ?? {value:''/*default Value*/}.value
```

**or**

```
 this.createCountryForm.get('countryCode')?.value
```

[For Detailed Explanation why formControl can be null check here](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#nullability)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't use a typed form, this `this.createCountryForm.get('countryCode')` (and the other too) can lead to a null object. Put a `!` after it: `this.createCountryForm.get('countryCode')!`.